# Problem on gcd of two numbers

Tags: divisibility

Let $(a,b)$ be the Greatest Common Divisor of two numbers $a$ and $b$.

Then, if $(r,n)=1$, is it true that $(r,n-r)=1$?

If correct, prove it.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you share any thoughts you have on the problem so far? Do you think the claim is true? Why or why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $(r,n)=1$. So there are numbers $r,s\in \mathbb Z$ such that $rx+ns=1$. we can use $rs$ and one can see that $rx+ns+rs-rs=1$. It implies that $(n-r)s+r(x+s)=1$ and we can conclude that $(n-r,r)=1$.

Answer (score 3):

If some divisor larger than $1$ divides $r$ and $n-r$ then it will have to divide their sum. (Think about what "divide" means to see this. $p$ divides $q$ if $q=kp$ for an integer $k$.)

Answer (score 1):

If $(r,n)=1$, then there is no integer $k$ such that $n=rk$. This means that there is no integer $k$ such, that $n-r=r(k-1)$. So, $(n-r,r)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read upon Euclid's algorithm to compute GCD. Not only will this answer your question but give you a lot more...

Comment: I agree on this.